# How to define a function in LISP which passes two Forms and then executes them randomly

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to LISP and I am currently trying to define a function that would pass two other forms that will be executed randomly. So for example, if I was to execute any form it would randomly execute one of the forms from a selection that would return the result.

would anyone know of any examples of this? I don't seem to know enough about LISP to form a web search that gets back the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

### Wrap a functional implementation with a macro…

[Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22289491/1281433) shows how to do this with functions.  I think that's the most sensible *implementation technique* for this problem.  [Wojciech Gac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22296091/1281433) suggests doing this with a macro.  I think that's the most natural *programming interface* for this problem (though, as noted in the comments, there are some issues with the macro in that answer).  Finally, I think it's worth combining these two techniques so that you have the benefit of the implementation (you can use function objects later if you want), as well as a convenient interface for the rest of the time.

```lisp
(defun call-one (functions)
  (funcall (nth (random (length functions)) functions)))

(defmacro one-of (&body forms)
  `(call-one (list ,@(mapcar (lambda (form)
                               `(lambda ()
                                  ,form))
                             forms))))
```

```
(call-one (list (constantly 3) (constantly 4)))
;=> 4 ; or 3

(one-of 3 4)
;=> 3 ; or 4
```

This type of macro implementation technique, where the main functionality is implemented as a function and the macro is implemented in terms of the function is good practice when applicable, in my opinion.  It's often easier to implement the functionality as a function, since you have fewer concerns about name capture, constructing forms, etc. Having the functional implementation available to you can be useful sometimes, so you have that added bit of flexibility.  Implementing the macro in terms of the function means that the macro is really acting as syntactic sugar for you;  conceptually all you need to do is wrap some individual forms in anonymous functions, and that's a task for macro that isn't too complex.   This doesn't work for every macro of course but, in my opinion, when it's applicable, it leads to code that is more maintainable, and that's less buggy from the beginning.

### But avoid redundant work…

There is one notable problem here, though.  The expansion of `one-of` creates a list and passes it to `call-one`:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(one-of 3 4))
;=> (CALL-ONE (LIST (LAMBDA () 3) (LAMBDA () 4)))
```

`call-one` computes the length of the list of functions and generates a random number.  For most calls, that's fine, but it is not great for expansions of `one-of`, because it means that we recompute the length of a list that never changes again and again.   When we use `one-of`, we can compute `(length functions)` at macroexpansion time, but we still need a way to provide it to `call-one`.  Thus, we can change the functional interface a little bit by adding an optional argument to `call-one` that defaults to `(length functions)`.  In the expansion of `one-of`, we simply provide a constant value.

```
(defun call-one (functions &optional (len (length functions)))
  (funcall (nth (random len) functions)))

(defmacro one-of (&body forms)
  `(call-one (list ,@(mapcar (lambda (form)
                               `(lambda ()
                                  ,form))
                             forms))
             ,(length forms)))
```

Thus we get this expansion:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(one-of 3 4))
;=> (CALL-ONE (LIST (LAMBDA () 3) (LAMBDA () 4)) 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This takes an arbitrary number of functions, and calls one of them at random:

```
(defun execute-one (&rest funcs)
  (let* ((random-pos (random (length funcs)))
         (func (nth random-pos funcs)))
    (funcall func)))

(execute-one
  (lambda () (print 3))
  (lambda () (print 5))
  (lambda () (print 10)))
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, in Barmar's answer the forms supplied to `execute-one` need to be of `lambda` type and be zero-argument. I suggest implementing it as a macro:

```
(defmacro execute-one (&body funcs)
  `(let* ((random-pos (random (length ',funcs)))
      (func (nth random-pos ',funcs)))
     (eval func)))
```

Now you can supply arbitrary forms and `execute-one` will evaluate one of them at random.

Example:

```
(execute-one
  (+ 10 100)
  (* 234 934)
  (expt 2 100))

=> 110
```

EDIT:
I've been able to exorcise `eval` from it:

```
(defmacro execute-one (&body funcs)
  `(let* ((random-pos (random (length ',funcs)))
      (func (nth random-pos ',funcs)))
     (apply #'funcall func)))
```

@Rainer, apart from `eval`, could you elaborate on why it's bad style?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses. They are helping me understand this better. 

Once I have created something I will post and show. But just wanted to say thanks for the really quick responses. :)

Comment: This macro is bad style. Especially since it uses EVAL.

Comment: @Wojciech The formatting (indentation) could also use some work,
but that's not a serious technical problem.  What's more
important is that this doesn't work. (i) The final macro version
doesn't work as the first example you gave.  You can `(eval '(+
10 100))`, but you can't `(apply #'funcall '(+ 10 100))`. (ii)
What happens if one of the code blocks happens to use a variable
named `random-pos`?  (iii) While you need to generate a random
number each time, there's no reason to call `length` each
time. Since the number of provided forms is fixed, you can
compute `(length funcs)` at compile time.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, as for (i), I can actually run `(apply #'funcall '(+ 10 100))` in SBCL and get 110 in response. What exactly do you mean by "can't"? :)

Comment: @WojciechGac I'm sorry, that particular example *does* work, because you can do `(funcall '+ '10 '100)`. However, you can't apply `funcall` to arbitrary forms and have it work. E.g., you can't do `(apply #'funcall '(let ((x 10)) (+ x 100)))`, because you can't do `(funcall 'let '((x 10)) '(+ x 100))`. Also, you really should remove the `eval` version; it simply won't work in lots of cases. E.g., `(let ((x 10)) (execute-one x))` will fail.